# No puedo acceder a una carpeta de mi sitio web

Tags: php, apache, apache2, plesk

tengo un sitio web en donde si yo accedo a la página principal del sitio no me muestra ningún problema y puedo acceder a el con éxito. El problema esta que dentro del sitio tengo una carpeta llamada chamilo y al tratar de acceder a ella me da el error 404 como si la ruta no existiera.

Me pueden ayudar, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Intenta agregar una barra al final de la url

```
189.201.128.227/chamilo/
```